# How to customize file filtering in Unity dash

Tags: unity, customization, unity-dash

I'm getting used to a new way of working in Unity and am really enjoying it.  The hardest thing I face now is tweaking it so that it works as nicely as possible.  On the face of it, customisation is very limited.

super+f -> filter to show documents.  Hmmm.  The most common document format I use after .txt files is .lyx files.  They really are documents.  They look a bit unhappy down in the 'other' category.  Is there any way to change this?

What I would *really* like is to make documents the default, because 'recent' gets completely filled up with photos.

Answer (score 1):

In 11.10 you can filter your results to suit the file type you are looking for.

Open the Dash and select the Find Files tab.

[image: Dash - files search]

You can then select the filter results drop down arrow and then highlight the Documents tab, in the search field you can type the file extension for the type of document you are looking for.

[image: Dash - filter documents search]

You can further filter by last modified.

This also works for Audio, Images, Video's etc.

Comment: I can't test this as my dash is currently broken.  I'm waiting for 12.04 to see if it starts working again.  Since .lyx files are not counted as documents (as I posted), I expect your suggestion is more of a work-around.  I would need to select Type=All, and then do *.lyx.  There is no way to associate .lyx files with the filter 'documents'.